# Problema con "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in..."

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Cuando intento generar un archivo PDF con datos de un formularios me sale el error:

> "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be
> mysqli_result, bool given in ...\src\pdf\generar.php on line 14"

Este es el código implementado:

```
require_once '../../conexion.php';
require_once 'fpdf/fpdf.php';
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'letter');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 10);
$pdf->SetTitle("Ventas");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$id = $_GET['v'];
$idcliente = $_GET['cl'];
$config = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM configuracion");
$datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($config);
$cliente = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM `cliente` WHERE `idcliente` = $idcliente");
$datosC = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cliente);
$ventas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT d.*, p.codproducto, p.descripcion FROM detalle_venta d INNER JOIN producto p ON d.id_producto = p.codproducto WHERE d.id_venta = $id");
$contador = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ventas)) {
    $pdf->Cell(14, 5, $contador, 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(90, 5, $row['descripcion'], 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, $row['cantidad'], 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(32, 5, $row['precio'], 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell(35, 5, number_format($row['cantidad'] * $row['precio'], 2, '.', ','), 0, 1, 'L');
    $contador++;
}
$pdf->Output("ventas.pdf", "I");
?>
```

Vale decir que ya he probado todas las consultas SQL directamente desde el `phpmyadmin` y todas me resultan correctas.

Alguna idea que pueda ayudarme?

Comment: Como sabes que todas tus `query` están correctas, puedes hacer un `var_dump($ventas->num_rows);` y lo agregas a tu consulta

Comment: Al parecer me faltaban las comillas simples en `$idcliente` pero ahora cuando genera el PDF no recibe la información del cliente.

Comment: eso es otra pregunta para otro post...

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($row); ` dentro del `while` y dinos qué muestra.